# Browser error in (IE 6)?

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, cross-browser

i developed a project in that when when i click on any button it giving some message like..

> sys.webforms.pagerequestmanagerservererrorexception:An
>   unknown error occurred while
>   processing the request on the status
>   code returned from the server
>   was:12019

it is especially in IE 7. it is working fine in firefox and IE 6. I have a doubt that when  a system contain IE 6 and IE 7 this problem will get i think what do you say?. can u help me
and this is my site

Comment: ya exactly when i click on any button it goes to server
this is my url: freakynuts.begoniaprojects.com can u check out please

Comment: thank you for response Mr.stakx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try at this ["FIX" for Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException 12019 Problem with MultipleIEs](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2008/04/24/fix-for-syswebformspagerequestmanagerse.aspx)

Comment: i copy paste the msxml3.dll in to Interexplore folder even though it is giving errors Mr. Pandiya Chendur